# Rubymine database connections detecotor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rubymineを起動すると下記の警告が出るのですがどうすれば直るでしょうか

[image: エラー]

Runした時のコンソールは下記の通りです。赤い文字なのですが問題ないのでしょうか？
ローカル環境にはアクセスできます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どちらも警告ではないですから、そのままで問題ないと思います。

前者は「データベースへの接続情報を見つけたけど RubyMine に設定するかい？」といった内容ですし、後者は起動したWEBrickのバージョン、プロセスID、ポート番号が表示されてるだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。安心しました。